# http://facebook.com to get property LocaFacebook JS Error - Permission denied to get property Location.href from http://www.mysite.com

Tags: facebook

Simply loading the standard Facebook connect JS framework and getting the following error:

Permission denied for facebook.com to get property Location.href /www.mysite.com

The error happens on line 127 in the file :
static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_US/js/Api/CanvasUtil/Connect/XFBML

Using FF 3.5.7 and Firebug 1.5.0

Is anyone else getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue falsely reported by Firebug.  Nothing to worry about.